# Cloudinary bulk image upload in Node.js ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

So I'm trying to upload a bulk of images to cloudinary in a small JavaScript script in Node.js but after a number of uploads, I get this error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.200.235.1:443
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
```

I've transformed my code into the simplest possible example and I still do get the error.

```
fs.readdir(".", (err, files) => {
 files.forEach(fileName => {
  cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
  fileName,
   { folder: "test4" },
   (err, fileResponse) => {
     if (err) throw err;
   }
  );
 });
});
```

I have tried adding a timeout parameter  `{timeout:60000}` which was suggested [here](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/206078351-How-can-I-increase-the-timeout-when-uploading-to-Cloudinary-), but it didn't work and also I couldn't find this property in the official docs. Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using by delaying time in between uploads. This would prevent the ETIMEDOUT error.